# My Two DataGrid XAML Resources are Mutually Exclusive --- Why?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

In order to have a nicer look, I am trying to add to my `DataGrid` 2 features that I found in separate places, but for some reason they just can't get along.

I can either have the section inside the blue rectangle or the one in the red one.

[image]

TIA

Comment: That is an excellent question - I had a similar problem and couldn't figure it out. Looking forward for an expert to elucidate.

Comment: What error message are you getting when you have the 2 sections uncommented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `<ControlTemplate>` tag *inside* the `<ResourceDictionary>` tag, underneath the closing `</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>` tag.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes\DataGrid.Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="SelectAllButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle x:Name="Border" Fill="LightBlue" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```